# Spring boot cannot resolve view page

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run a simple web application with using Spring Boot but there is a problem with resolving view. When I go to http://localhost:8080/ it shows;

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Is there any missing property or library? Why it cannot resolve my html page?

My application.properties;

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: WEB-INF/html/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .html
```

[image]

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}



@Controller
public class InfoController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getServerInfo(Map<String, Object> model){

        //This method works without any problem.

        model.put("message", "server info");
        return "info";  

    }

}
```

Comment: did you tried to move the html under resources folder?

Comment: @shahaf yes still not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use spring boot with some template engine, for example, thymeleaf. You don't need to set `spring.mvc.view.prefix` or `spring.mvc.view.suffix` by default.

You just need to put your template files under the directory `src/main/resources/templates/`:
[image]

And your controller will be something like:

```
@GetMapping("/temp")
public String temp(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("attr", "attr");
    return "index";
}
```

If you are **NOT** using any template engine and just want to serve HTML page as static content, put your HTML files under the directory `src/main/resources/static/`:
[image]

And your controller will become:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    return "test.html";
}
```

Comment: What if I use JSP? My JSPs are in the templates folder, but I get the same message: "Cannot resolve MVC view 'users'"

Answer (score 5):

if you are using thymeleaf for spring boot. just add below to `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try create tree of files like in [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

```
src/main/resources/static
```

or

```
src/main/resources/templates/ //here put html files
```

Comment: Moved info.html to "src/main/resources/templates/" and removed spring.mvc.view.prefix from properties but still getting same 404 error.

Comment: Give me github with this app. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

putting in here worked for me in a spring-boot web sample:

```
src/main/webapp/index.xhtml
```

then in the browser enter:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

here is a linkt to the sample:

```
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-primefaces-integration.html
```