# Thymeleaf throws exception (TemplateInputException) with message "Error resolving template [books/list]:..."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is a simple project where I have tried to practice Thymeleaf and .html relations. Here are the details:

list.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Spring Framework Simple Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book List</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
        <td th:text="${book.id}">123</td>
        <td th:text="${book.title}"> Spring in Action</td>
        <td th:text="${book.publisher.name}">Wrox</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

in BookController, return path is showing "Cannot Resolve MVC 'view'":

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookController(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping( "/books")
    public String getBooks(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("books", bookRepository.findAll());

        return "books/list";
    }
}
```

I have tried different thymeleaf dependencies:

```
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have already tried below links:

[Spring boot cannot resolve view page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364084/spring-boot-cannot-resolve-view-page/49364255)

[Spring - Cannot resolve MVC "view" thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002080/spring-cannot-resolve-mvc-view-thymeleaf)

[Spring boot + thymeleaf in IntelliJ: cannot resolve vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710585/spring-boot-thymeleaf-in-intellij-cannot-resolve-vars)

[TemplateInputException: Error resolving template ****, template might not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283649/templateinputexception-error-resolving-template-template-might-not-exist)

https://www.programmersought.com/article/12644906098/

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

but without any luck. I have read that this is some kind of bug in IntelliJ and tried to do fix it but still not working.

Please, any help and suggestions are welcomed and appreciated in advance for effort.

Path to my .html file:

[/home/panda/IdeaProjects/udemyClass/src/main/resources/templates.books/list.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RNCC.png)

Comment: Could you please provide path to list.html, to check that this html exists on defined path.

Comment: @Ishikawa Yoshi I have added to the post with new edit.

Comment: Check that templates and books are separeted folders and not one folder with name templates.books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your folder wasn't created properly. Look closely at your path: resources/**templates.books**/list.html

so, in order to make it work:

```
return "templates.books/list";
```

or delete this stuff and create the folder in a proper way: delete books folder, and before adding it again, just create any file in templates directory.

Answer (score 0):

@Balthazar thanks for your reply. I have recreated the same path and after it looks like this now:

/home/panda/IdeaProjects/udemyClass/src/main/resources/templates/books/list.html

It is working as expected now.